# How to applying a datatemplate automatically by type, but also using it by key in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate

I'm trying to populate the contents of an `ItemControl` with instances of various types, where each of them should have their own data template assigned. Now some of them might be nested within another type, or might appear at the root of the collection, but I'd like to use the same data template for both.

```
<ItemsControl Items="{Binding MyItems}">
  <ItemsControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate Type="{x:Type MyType1}">
      <!-- contains this stuff -->
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate Type="{x:Type MyType2}>
      <!-- contains that stuff -->
    </DataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate Type="{x:Type MyType3WhichHostsType1}" ItemsSource="{Children}">
      <SomeWrapperStuff>
        <ItemsControl Items="{Children}" ItemsTemplate="HOW?" /> <--- this part
      </SomeWrapperStuff>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

The problem is, once I assign a key to the data template of `MyType1`, it stops being resolved automatically for all instances at the root of the collection, and instead only works within the nested `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. Is there a XAML-way of telling the `ItemsControl` that it should both resolve the template for an item by type, while I can still reference it as static resource by key?

Comment: Setting the ItemTemplate isn't even necessary with auto-selected DataTemplates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is because when you specify a DataTemplate in a ResourceDictionary with a DataType and no x:Key, WPF creates an implicit value for x:Key equal to "{x:Type [value of DataType property]}". So your DataTemplate always has a key.

As such, when you explicitly provide a key value, you are effectively replacing that Type-based key with another key, which causes WPF to no longer match the DataTemplate to its intended elements.

A workaround is to clone the DataTemplate, specifying x:Key in one and omitting it in the other.

Comment: Oh! I wasn't aware of the fact that the type is being used to implicitly create a key if not stated. That makes sense in that case. I now ended up with creating my own generic `DataTemplateSelector` which allows me to assign data templates by types where as I can still reference them by key if I need to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow up to my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66605384/how-to-applying-a-datatemplate-automatically-by-type-but-also-using-it-by-key-i#comment117742985_66605515) should anyone else looking for a similiar solution, however I'm leaving the accepted answer since I specifically asked for a pure XAML solution.

This simple `DataTemplateSelector` allows to assign several templates by type (with also checking whether an item is of a derived type of a template key-pair specified), while still allowing to assign a key to them.

```
public class TypeDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector {
  public Collection<TypeDataTemplate> Templates { get; } = new Collection<TypeDataTemplate>();

  public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container) =>
    item != null 
      ? Templates.Where(templatePair => IsDerivedOfType(item.GetType(), templatePair.Type))
        .Select(templatePair => templatePair.Template).FirstOrDefault() : null;

  private static bool IsDerivedOfType(Type itemType, Type baseType) {
    while (true) {
      if (itemType == baseType) return true;
      if (itemType.BaseType == null) return false;
      itemType = itemType.BaseType;
    }
  }
}

public class TypeDataTemplate { 
  public Type Type { get; set; }
  public DataTemplate Template { get; set; }
}
```

Example usage:

```
<MyControl.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeTemplate1" />
  <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeTemplate2" />
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SomeTemplateWithChildren" ItemsSource="...">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="..." ItemsTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTemplate1}" />
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  <TypeDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTypeDataTemplateSelector">
    <TypeDataTemplateSelector.Templates>
      <TypeDataTemplate Type="{x:Type SomeType1}" Template="{StaticResource SomeTemplate1}" />
      <TypeDataTemplate Type="{x:Type SomeType2}" Template="{StaticResource SomeTemplate2}" />
      <TypeDataTemplate Type="{x:Type SomeTypeWithChildren}" Template="{StaticResource SomeTemplateWithChildren}" />
    </TypeDataTemplateSelector.Templates>
  </TypeDataTemplateSelector>
</MyControl.Resources>
...
<ItemsControl Items="{Binding SomeItems}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTypeDataTemplateSelector}" />
```